# Access parent properties in angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

Here, I created an object say d.

```
var d={
  a:"firstName",
  b:"lastName"
};
```

Now I want to create another object say A, which inherits properties of d.

```
var A=Object.create(d);

console.log(A.a);//returns "firstName"
console.log(A.b);//returns "lastName"
```

But when I uses
    console.log(A);// returns empty object, as it doesn't show inherited properties.

But it creates little problem while using with angular.forEach.

I want to use angular.forEach which parse all properties including inherited properties. How can I loop through object including parent properties?

I have to use Object.create as parent object is dynamic, i.e. It may include more objects in future, and these properties will automatically comes in child object. Here **I cant use angular.copy** as it does deep copy and breaks relation between parent object.

**In previous version of google chrome, see inherited properties also. But after updating to version 43.0.2357.52, its not showing inherited properties in console**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Angular has a specific function for it (I didn't see one), but you can use JavaScript's `for-in` loop to see those:

```
var key;
for (key in d) {
    // key will be "firstName" on one pass and "lastName" on another
    // there IS NO guarantee of order
}
```

`for-in` visits both own properties and inherited ones.

Comment: This is a good way answer :) , but any other way to do it with angularjs only?

Comment: @LaxmikantDange: If there is, I don't see it in the API docs, but I'm not an Angular expert.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use angular.copy() to do this:

```
var A = angular.copy(d);
```

Comment: good to know that angular has a predefined function for it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `angular.forEach` does not iterate over inherited properties and it does not have any function that does it.

> ... It is worth noting that .forEach does not iterate over inherited properties because it filters using the hasOwnProperty method... [angular 1.4](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

You need implement you own function.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, log);
expect(log).toEqual(['name: misko', 'gender: male']);
```

I found this example  on [documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)